# Get Reference From TableViewCells in TableView iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

It is my first time to do an app that has a 'generic'-ish design, in which the textFields and buttons are **inside the tableView cells**. I'm having quite a hard time **getting the values of the texFields in my dynamic tableView cells.**

Here's my code:

```
func submit() {

    // cells
    let nameCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)) as! ProductDetailTableViewCell
    let shortDescriptionCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 1)) as! ProductDetailTableViewCell

    // data
    let name = nameCell.textField_Detail.text!
    ...
    ...
}
```

It works, however, it crashes the app when you scroll to the bottom of the tableView and you attempt to call this **submit()** function. Any ideas how to properly get the values of the textFields inside these dynamic cells?

EDIT:
The crash points to the **nameCell**

*fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

[image]

Comment: What is the message when it crashes?

Comment: Also, which line does it crash on?

Comment: see the edit, guys.

Comment: cellForRow could be returning something that is not a `ProductDetailTableViewCell`, is that the only type that it ever returns?

Comment: @Samantha, yes, ProductDetailTableViewCell is for the whole section1 and section3. section0 and section2 are different.

Comment: I think the problem is that cellForRow will return nil if the cell is not visible. "as!" means force cast to the given type. You cannot cast nil to your cell type.

Comment: cellForRow shouldn't be able to return `nil`. Its return type is `UITableViewCell`. I would double-check the class that is getting returned. Maybe there is a fallback case that returns something default? Or perhaps something else on that line is nil, like `tableView`? (This would be odd though.)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow here is the doc

Comment: Oh shoot. I was looking at this one. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview .. In any case using `as?` to cast to `ProductDetailTableViewCell?` might prevent the crash, but then you'd still need to figure out the `nil` part.

Comment: I doubled check, of course, I'm getting nil whenever the cell is not visible. Casting doesn't help, I think.

Comment: Does your controller implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol? It seems like `self.tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1))` might not return `nil` where the other one does.

Comment: Yes of course, that's why I got the whole project working except when I need to call this submit() function which needs a reference to each cells in the tableView. I'll do a research too. *oops, there's a new answer. checking...

Comment: This seems incredibly wrong.  Is this a form, with some fields (say, firstName, lastName and so on)... ?  In the page which holds the table just have references to the items.

Comment: Hey Joe, Yes, this is a form, but I need to make it dynamic as the users can add an information as much as he wants (per information is one new cell). I've solved it by the way. Using the freakin tags. Thanks @Samantha for the effort +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do an "if let" in order to get this optional value and avoid the crash with nil values

Example:

```
if let myNameCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)) as! ProductDetailTableViewCell{
    // Here you must use 'myNameCell'
}
```

And for getting the values of the TextFields inside the cell I like to assign a Tag to each TextField and then get the value by this way:

```
if let myNameCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)) as! ProductDetailTableViewCell{
   (myNameCell.contentView.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel).text = "bla bla bla"
   (myNameCell.contentView.viewWithTag(3) as! UITextField).text = "Some text!"
}
```

Comment: TAGS is the only way huhu. Thanks!